# Pulling elements from mongodb array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a question for which I've wasted more time than I should have and I don't seem to get what I'm doing wrong.

I have the below document in MongoDB:

```
{
    "personal": {
        ...
    },
    "preferences": {
        ....
    },
    "_id": "5b2efdad564191054807c2b1",
    "pets": [],
    "conversations": [
        {
            "unread": 1,
            "participants": [
                {
                    "_id": "5b2efdcd564191054807c2b2",
                    "name": "Mighty Jules"
                }
            ],
            "messages": [
                {
                    "sender": "self",
                    "timestamp": "2018-06-24T12:29:50.656Z",
                    "_id": "5b2f8ebede342a12a8dcc9d2",
                    "text": "..."
                },
                {
                    "sender": "self",
                    "timestamp": "2018-06-24T12:29:58.022Z",
                    "_id": "5b2f8ec6de342a12a8dcc9d8",
                    "text": "..."
                },
                {
                    "sender": "5b2efdcd564191054807c2b2",
                    "timestamp": "2018-06-24T12:30:27.562Z",
                    "_id": "5b2f8ee3de342a12a8dcc9e5",
                    "text": "..."
                },
                {
                    "sender": "self",
                    "timestamp": "2018-06-24T12:32:48.034Z",
                    "_id": "5b2f8f70d3a83e25bc1abbb2",
                    "text": "..."
                },
                {
                    "sender": "self",
                    "timestamp": "2018-06-24T12:36:20.027Z",
                    "_id": "5b2f9044d4137828283c5a60",
                    "text": "..."
                },
                {
                    "sender": "5b2efdcd564191054807c2b2",
                    "timestamp": "2018-06-24T12:37:39.965Z",
                    "_id": "5b2f90939b4b2a4af8cf50db",
                    "text": "..."
                }
            ],
            "last_message": "2018-06-24T12:37:39.965Z",
            "_id": "5b2efdcd564191054807c2b2"
        },
        {
            "unread": 1,
            "participants": [
                {
                    "_id": "5b300ff657957c1aa0ed0576",
                    "name": "Super Frank"
                }
            ],
            "messages": [
                {
                    "sender": "5b300ff657957c1aa0ed0576",
                    "timestamp": "2018-06-24T21:42:49.392Z",
                    "_id": "5b30105957957c1aa0ed0583",
                    "text": "..."
                }
            ],
            "last_message": "2018-06-24T21:42:49.392Z",
            "_id": "5b300ff657957c1aa0ed0576"
        }
    ],
    "created_date": "2018-06-24T02:10:53.314Z",
    "lastLogin_date": "2018-06-24T02:10:53.314Z",
    "lastUpdate_date": "2018-06-25T02:09:53.281Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

I am trying to delete just a couple of messages using mongoose:

```
const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5b2efdad564191054807c2b1"), //Which is the one that doc
        "conversations._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5b2efdcd564191054807c2b2")
    },
    {
        $pull: {
            "conversations.$.messages": {
                $in: [
                    { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5b2f9044d4137828283c5a60") },
                    { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5b2f90939b4b2a4af8cf50db") }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        new: true,
        projection: {
            conversations: 1
        }
    }
);
```

In the response I get the same, nothing gets deleted, I get no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `_id`s in the example document are strings, not `ObjectId`. 
Secondly, the $pull syntax is wrong. Please read https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#remove-items-from-an-array-of-documents. It should be:

```
{
    $pull: {
        "conversations.$.messages": { 
            "_id": {
                "$in": ["5b2f9044d4137828283c5a60", "5b2f90939b4b2a4af8cf50db"]
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

It will pull messages from the **first** matching conversation, if it is what you want. If you want to remove messages from **all** matching conversations, you need to use [$[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) instead: `"conversations.$[].messages"`

Comment: They are strings when parsed by res.json, I should have clarified that (here's how they look: https://i.imgur.com/fJEIqWn.png). And yes I want from the first matching conversation, I am actually filtering by that (doc _id and conversation._id). And also, they are documents, not array of strings, so in your example it should indicate that they are indeed _id: "..."

Comment: @Wisdoom please read the docs behind the link. The syntax of $pull is other way round, not `$in[{_id: id1}, {id: id2}]` as in your question but `_id: {$in: [id1, id2]}` as I put in the answer. Whatever ids are strings or objects.

Comment: This works, what I was doing wrong, that I didn't see on your response, is that I had $in { _id: whatever }, but it should have been _id: { $in: [what, ever]}. I knew it was a silly thing, I just didn't realize that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
function exists(Arr, objId){
    for(var i = 0; i < Arr.length; i++)
        if(objId.equals(Arr[i]))
            return true    
    return false
}

var user = await User.findOne(
    {_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5b2efdad564191054807c2b1")}
)

for(var j = 0; j<user.conversations.length; j++)
    if(exists([conId],user.conversations[j]._id)
        break

if(j<user.conversations.length)
for(var i =0; i < user.conversations[j].messages.length; i++)
    if(exists(Arr, user.conversations.messages[i]._id))
        delete user.conversations.messages[i]        

user.save()
```

---

**Edit: using only db operations**

If you want to use $in then you will have to pass the whole sub array.

```
await User.update({_id : "5b2efdad564191054807c2b1", "conversations._id" : "5b2efdcd564191054807c2b2" }, { $pull: { "conversations.$.messages":{ $in : [{"sender" : "self", "timestamp" : "2018-06-24T12:32:48.034Z","_id" : "5b2f8f70d3a83e25bc1abbb2","text" : "..."}] } } }, {multi : true} )
```

something like that as $in compares the whole document to each element in the array.

In your case it does not find a match but still it succeeded in the process and hence no error.

if you want to do only by id you will have to loop through for each of your ids as follows

```
for(var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++)
    await User.update({_id : "5b2efdad564191054807c2b1", "conversations._id" : "5b2efdcd564191054807c2b2" }, { $pull: { "conversations.$.messages": {_id : ids[i] } } }, {multi : true} )
```

or you know the _id field so use in to search for $id

```
await User.update({_id : "5b2efdad564191054807c2b1", "conversations._id" : "5b2efdcd564191054807c2b2" }, { $pull: { "conversations.$.messages":{ "_id" : { $in : ids } } } }, {multi : true} )
```

Comment: Why would I do all that when the pull should work? Why would I do the work on my side, when the DB should do it? If I where to do something like that, why wouldn't I get the list of messages and remove them manually and then $set them again?